# how to check open file without lsof

Tags: android, lsof

In linux, I use lsof to check the file is opened by which process. I have an android device, but no lsof command. Is it possible to find which process open the specific file ?

I will use it to verify the MediaPlayer hold a fd, but it should be closed.

Comment: 'lsof' is added to [ICS](http://androidxref.com/source/history/system/core/toolbox/Android.mk), commit `8b9b105bc7bf6428591d55462b3e727ba7504b29`. Lift it from the source, rip out the required bits and build it using the NDK if it doesn't exist on the versions you are targeting.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Poor man's lsof is to execute

```
ls -l  /proc/[process id]/fd
```

Still, you need to be root.

Comment: `ls -l /proc/*/fd` to see all open files like lsof does by default.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks mike jones and Joqn for the tip with poor man's lsof.  I used it in the following on busybox (synology nas) to list the fd directories grouped under each process:

```
  for p in [0-9]*; do ls -l /proc/$p/fd ;done
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like this needs to be run inside the /proc folder - maybe it should more generally be `for p in /proc/[0-9]*; do ls -l $p/fd; done`?

Answer (score 1):

Install busybox, it has a lsof command.

Comment: I used busy box but still im getting "????"   how can i get the values is it a different command by any chance ??

Comment: im already on root  access ,  the command runs and give out a table and im expecting values , but all what im getting is Question marks "????"   any ideas thanx

Comment: I installed Busybox on my phone, but it does not provide me the lsof command :-(  Maybe this is phone-specific, but I don't find it in the applet list.

Comment: There are statically linked busybox binaries for most architectures here: http://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Combining the above /proc based with the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513133/how-do-i-find-all-of-the-symlinks-in-a-directory-tree/21438684) about searching a directory tree for symlinks gives the following:

```
# find /proc -ignore_readdir_race -name task -prune -o -path '*/fd/*' -lname '/file/of/interest' -ls -quit
 37023    0 l-wx------   1 username  username        64 Dec 16 09:06 /proc/4140/fd/1 -> /file/of/interest
```

The `-ignore_readdir_race` avoids errors due to short lived processes, the `-prune` gets rid of task level results (not strictly necessary when stopping at the first process, since those paths would still give the same answer, but useful to avoid redundancy in other use cases, like listing all the results)

Combine `-print` with `cut` to extract the pid directly:

```
# find /proc -ignore_readdir_race -name task -prune -o -path '*/fd/*' -lname '/file/of/interest' -print -quit | cut -d / -f 3
4140
```

Once you have the pid, you can use ps to get the process details (as per the answers to [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/632979/if-i-know-the-pid-number-of-a-process-how-can-i-get-its-name)):

```
# ps -p 4140 -o command=
/some/command --with=some args
```

(Note, I tested this on Linux, and it should work the same on BSD, but I'm not 100% sure about Android)