# File locked by which process (android)?

Tags: java, android

Currently I am developing one android application in which I have a file on sdcard and I have to find out process id of all process which are accessing this file.

Using the android.os.FileObserver we can know only whether the file is accessed by any process. But how to get process id of that process?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible through Android SDK.

What you could be looking for is `lsof` (system) command. Unfortunately it's unavailable on most stock ROMs under Android 4.0. According to comment under [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796298/how-to-check-open-file-without-lsof), there has been a patch for ICS to add basic `lsof` support. I have Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.3 and I see that `lsof` command is present on my phone. You could also install BusyBox to install `lsof` (or require user of your applicatiion to install it).

Assuming that you have `lsof` present on phone you could parse output running command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "lsof", pathToInterestingFile});
```