# Error-63(file name too long) while unzipping a zip file downloaded from GitHub

Tags: ios, swift, git, github

I created my first repository in GitHub and pushed a XCode project into it. After downloading the .zip file in my Mac again, I cannot unzip it by double clicking(but can do it via terminal code) it as it reads out the error as -

**unable to expand the zip file to the folder. Error-63(File name too long)**

GitHub Link - [Link to my repository](https://github.com/GABHISEKBUNTY/customSegment.git)

So any solution to make the file be unzipped error free, so that any user downloading this might not face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have versioned a symlink which was translated into an infinite [loop to the folder `customSegment`](https://github.com/GABHISEKBUNTY/customSegment/tree/master/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment):

```
https://github.com/GABHISEKBUNTY/customSegment/tree/master/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment/customSegment
```

Make sure to remove that symlink, then add, commit and push again your repo.
Use a recent git ([2.3.2+ since it is more careful with symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28848070/6309))

The first test to do is to [look for those symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513194/6309):

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
find . -type l -ls
# rm the one referecing customSegment
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i remove the symlink. Please guide a bit as I am new to all this.

Comment: @G.Abhisek look for any symlink in your local repo (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8513194/6309)

Comment: my git version is - git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61) . I tried to do the steps mentioned in the above answer but couldn't . Can you please give the step from scretch.

Comment: @gab what did you type? What did you see? The link above for symlinks does not involve git.

Comment: actually can you please tell what terminal commands I need one by one to remove the symlink ?

Comment: @G.Abhisek I have edited the answer to illustrate the type of commands to use

Comment: I used the command as follows - cd desktop->cd MyFolder->cd customSegment. This is my project which I did upload in gitHub. Now I cannot find my local repo, it isn't visible also. So what to do now. Please guide me along.

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot of terminal codes that I am using.

Comment: @G.Abhisek Replace `cd /path/to/my/repo` by `cd desktop/MyFodler/customSegment`, then type  `find . -type l -ls`

Comment: Nothing is coming after I do so, when I write "find . -type l -ls" ,  it just moves me to next line.

Comment: @G.Abhisek Can you do: `cd desktop/MyFodler/customSegment/customSegment`, `git rm -r customSegment`, `git add -A .`; and `git push`? Then you can try again download the zip for that updated repo, and try unzipping it.

Comment: its showing   fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

Comment: @G.Abhisek then let's do just that: `git push --set-upstream origin master`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110471/discussion-between-g-abhisek-and-vonc).

Comment: this is the o/p - Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin. 
Everything up-to-date  But still can't unzip the file

Comment: @G.Abhisek I dno't see a new push in https://github.com/GABHISEKBUNTY/customSegment

Comment: But i did that, and I also gave what o/p I got ?

Comment: @G.Abhisek Try again: clone your repo elsewhere, go to that elsewhere, repeat the git rm command, add, commit, push again for testing.