# Remove all links (aliases) in a directory (tree)

Tags: bash, rm, ln

I have a directory of directories which may or may not contain files, other directories or links.

I want to delete all the links. Anyone know of a bash script that would let me do this quickly?

Comment: Honest inquiry; why was my question down voted? Asking to learn what to keep in mind when writing my next one. Downvote without comment is very misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search to *find all links in a directory* leads to:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

You can combine this with `rm`:

```
rm `find . -maxdepth 1 -type l`
```

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? The maxdepth is cautionary, but easy to remove if the OP doesn't want it, and I *SURE* hope he reads the manpage before arbitrarily executing code he doesn't understand... I do get that the OP asked for recursive deletes, but a downvote on this seems like someone was maybe just looking for a badge?

Answer (score 0):

c.f. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513133/how-do-i-find-all-of-the-symlinks-in-a-directory-tree)

If you're brave, try this -

```
find $dirPath -type l | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: You should be careful with this command, it deletes links recursively, i.e. all links in any sub directory (and sub-sub-...-directories).

Comment: Yes, it's quick but very heavy-handed. I would most likely just write the list to a file and eyeball it first, then edit if needed, and when satisfied, feed that list to the xargs, or some other script. ...but it matches the request.